# Process.Start for any exe fails sometimes on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have ASP.Net code running on IIS(Windows Server 2016). Our Asp.Net code starts external exe. Normally everything works. But sometimes exe fails to start. When that happens only full restart of computer resolves the problem.

I wrote test code to start just notepad.exe. It will work for sometime and start notepad.exe when we need. Again after sometime it fails to start notepad.exe and all continuous calls will fail. Restarting IIS will not help. Restarting PC will solve the problem.

```
  ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo =
    new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\notepad.exe");

   Process process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
   process.Start()
```

I expect notepad.exe start to work everytime. Or at least if it fails get some meaningful exception with description why it failed. I am wondering maybe it is some kind of IIS DoS protection. Our application is resource intensive and this failure occurs after many hours of running the web site.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting exception. That would really help if i got one...

Answer (score 0):

Using Notepad.exe is a bad example for you to be testing with as it has UI components hopefully your external.exe does not.

IIS does not have any "DoS" type protection like you describe.

Two things I would try:
1) Process.Start() returns a bool.  If false is returned, then add some error logging to the application dumping out info from the Process object.
2) Since the issue is easy to reproduce once it starts occuring Run Sysinternals ProcMon and see if you get any Process Start Events and look at the Process Terminate events.

Comment: notepad was just random choice for testing. Process.Start returns false. But no exception with description of what went wrong. If you want more details, actually the reall application we use is ou-of-process COM server. When we create that COM object the error we are getting is CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE. Also exe gets started for very brief moment and shutsdown . I can see that in TaskMgr. Same behavior if you try to just start the real exe, and same behavior with notepad exe. Again eveything works for any of those until that moment in time when it just stops working. Really strange.

Comment: Really strange. Also when computer is in this error state i can easily create that COM object in test console application, of course i can easily start notepad.exe as well. It is just something has to do with IIS process.